# How to make a bootable DVD with buzybox?

Tags: boot, busybox

I want to make a bootable DVD (from/with) busybox. Why? I don't know... yet.
I read the official instructions, but just can't get it.
So what the process is like? Can you give me an outline of it?
I am a hobbyist, I have never done this before. I learnt it was possible from official docs.
Here's what I mean. I download the linux kernel source code, busybox source code, what next?

Comment: @alecxs "The boy saw the girl with the telescope".  Was the girl carrying a telescope or was the boy a peeping tom?  Now read the question again.

Comment: busybox is just one component you need to get a working linux command line.  If you are looking for something truely minimal which is based on busybox then take a look at [AlpineLinux](https://www.alpinelinux.org/) and look for instructions for how to install it.

Comment: @alecxs only that the former is ambiguous and the later isn't. One interpretation of the former is the latter. English is an ugly language.

Comment: Thanks @PhilipCouling but I would like to try making another AlpineLinux, just for recreation purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly let me draw your attention to [Linux From Scratch](https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/) which is a maintained manual on how to build your own linux system from the ground up, compiling everything yourself.

There's a lot of complexity that other's have already worked through in LFS which I can't easily cover in a simple answer.  So even if LFS is overkill for what you want, it'd be worth reading through it to get a feel for the components they recommend and the setup required.

I'll also draw your attention to [Alpine Linux](http://alpinelinux.org) which is a minimal linux distribution based on busy-box.

If you still want to setup something yourself then read on...

### High level description of what you'll need

To start with I'd use a cheap USB drive or SD card.  Otherwise you'll end up binning a lot of wasted DVDs.  You start by making an image then flash that to a USB or burn it to DVD (it makes little difference).

You may also consider using a virtual machine such a VirtualBox to test your image rather than physically rebooting your machine every time you try to test your image.

#### Components you'll need in your image

To run linux you really only need three components on your CD:

1. a boot loader (grub? - others can be more simple to configure)
2. a compiled linux kernel
3. something to run (busybox)

The boot loader will need to be configured to load the kernel from a file and pass parameters over to the kernel.

Every linux system must have one program which runs for the whole time the system runs (known as "init).  When it exits the system basically crashes.  The [kernel parameters](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/bootparam.7.html) at minimum will need to include which file-system to mount (`root=`) and which single program to run (`init=`).

To run a truly minimal system the trick is that you configure linux to run `/bin/sh` (the command line) as "init".  IE: `init=/bin/sh`.

#### Busybox

Busybox is a single program which will behave as many other programs depending on its name - literally rename it and it does something different.

To use it, the easy thing to do is link create a link (hardlink or symbolic link) with the name of [every command it supports](https://boxmatrix.info/wiki/BusyBox-Commands), or at least every command you want.

#### Creating an image

You'll need to package everything in a single image file.  It's easiest to do this with a loopback device; partition then format then copy files in:

- Create a large file (eg use `truncate` or [`fallocate`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/fallocate.1.html))
- Setup a loopback device with [losetup](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/losetup.8.html).  *This lets you work with the file as if it's a device like a USB drive or hard-dive*
- Partition the drive with `cfdisk` or similar
- add the loopback partitions as devices with `partprobe`
- format the partitions as you want (eg `mkfs.ext4`)
- mount the partitions
- *write files / install bootloader*
- unmount, `partex -d`, `losetup -d`